# Render one view inside another in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

i have a comments section that gets called at 3 place in one place along with posts and at other two places solo.(comments only). Now using this as a element makes sense. But my posts are also rendered via a element. Does it makes sense to render a element inside another

Comment: Yep this is fine, I have a comments element which loops through comments and calls another element for each comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I knew about the elements I try to use whenever I can. They help you to minimize the code repetition. It's not unusual include elements inside another.

In fact, I use the same structure in the elements directory as the views directory to organize them.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer:

// Render the element in /View/Elements/ajaxreturn.ctp

$this->render('/Elements/ajaxreturn');

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with doing this. No clashes are going to occur as the variables are scoped

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1081/Elements

Answer (score 2):

Since version 2.1 you may embed one view into another by "Extending Views"

```
$this->extend('/Common/view');
```

([documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html))

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the 3 places you mention are handled by views no? So if you have a posts element and a comments element you can include the elements needs according to the view no? In one view you only use the comments element and in the other you only use both elements what do you think?